# Applying multiple buffers to roads through arcpy

Tags: python, buffer, arcpy

I'm looking to apply multiple buffer of 100, 200, 300, and 400 meters to the roads feature class of a geodatabase. I keep running into an error in executing tool.

This is my code:

```
distances = [100, 200, 300, 400]
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\public\Desktop\python\data\NewGeodatabase.gdb"
for distance in distances:
     arcpy.Buffer_analysis("roads", "roads_"+ str(distances) + "buff", distances, "FULL", "ROUND", "All")
```

Comment: Please include the error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is because of using `distances` instead of `distance` while creating a buffer

Correct code will be

```
distances = [100, 200, 300, 400]
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\public\Desktop\python\data\NewGeodatabase.gdb"
for distance in distances:
     # Change is on the following line - distances => distance
     arcpy.Buffer_analysis("roads", "roads_"+ str(distance) + "buff", distance, "FULL", "ROUND", "All")
```

If you want to define the unit of each distance separately for each buffer, you'll need the `distances` to be a list of strings where each string has the value and a valid unit i.e.

```
distances = ["100 Meters", "200 Miles", "300 Kilometers", "400 Feet"]
```